# Exclude some part of Python Syntax from MPI

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mpi

I'm currently facing a problem and I need your help! So I have a code that will call a Linux Terminal command from a python code. But, I also have some part of the code that needs to be run in parallel to accelerate the computation.

Roughly, the code (say, the name is `code.py`) will looks like this:

```
import parallel_func, cli_func

parallel_func() #this part is supposed to run in parallel when using mpirun 
cli_func() #this part is supposed to run without mpi
```

The problem is, if I run `mpirun -np 4 python code.py`, the `parallel_func` will do well, but the `cli_func` will run multiple cli_program that will overburden the cpu.

So, are there any way I can do to isolate that `cli_func` part from the MPI?

Thank you for your help!

edit: I've did the solution that [tobias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13549709/tobias) replied below (using mpi rank selection) but it results in running one rank with the `cli_func` with the rest of the cpu still running, limitting the usable processor for the cli program.

edit: I found the makeshift solution using this [mpi4py: substantial slowdown by idle cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170492/mpi4py-substantial-slowdown-by-idle-cores)
That fixed it all!

Answer (score 2):

First off, whenever you run a program using *MPI*, you will always have *n* instances of your program running in parallel.  Hence, what you probably want to achieve is that only *one* of those *n* programs running simultaneously executed the `cli_func()` part.

The *n* programs running in parallel all have a *rank*, a number between 0 and *n*-1, so that you can distinguish the programs running.  You can use that rank to make only one program perform a certain action.  If you use the [`mpi4py` library](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), this looks like so:

```py
import parallel_func, cli_func

from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

parallel_func()
if rank == 0:
    cli_func()
```

The condition `rank == 0` makes sure that only the instance with rank `0` executes the respective code.  But you can also choose any other rank, of course, or have different instances do different things.

```py
if rank == 0:
    print("First")
elif rank == 1:
    print("Second!")
```

You did not specify in your question what MPI Python package you are using.  Depending on this, the exact syntax might differ, although the idea will still be the same.

Comment: Wow! That helped dude. But there's still something not ideal happened. So the `cli_func` does run only on one rank, but the other ranks is still running at full performance despite doing nothing, do you have any idea?.

Comment: BTW, I'm shocked by your real quick response lol. Thank you dude haha :)

Comment: @Vieri_Wijaya  I am happy I could help.  Unfortunately, I have little experience with the problem of idle cores here, as my use cases are usually quite different.  My guess would have been to introduce some `time.sleep(.)` in a loop, which is also what the answer in the link seems to suggest.